# Merge the total amount month wise

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, json

I am getting data in tabular form. Now i need to merge the data of same month. Display the table like below. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance 
For example: Currently the table is like

```
Month | Total Amount
Jan   | 100
Jan   | 100
Mar   | 200
Apr   | 300
Apr   | 200
```

I want the output to be like

```
 Month | Total Amount
    Jan   | 200
    Mar   | 200
    Apr   | 500
```

Here is the code:

```
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.length > 0) {

            var tr;
            var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun","Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                var date = new Date(data[i].CompDt);

                var month = monthNames[date.getMonth()];
                var total = 0;
                var totalamt = data[i].TotalAmt;
                tr = $('<tr/>');
                tr.append("<td>" + month + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + totalamt + "</td>");
                $('#GraphTable').append(tr);
            }

            var total = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                total = total + data[i].TotalAmt;
            }
            $('#GraphTable').append('<tr style="font-weight: bold; background-color: white"><td colspan="2" align="right">Total: </td><td>' + total + '</td></tr>');
            tr = $('<tr style="font-weight: bold; background-color: white" />');
            tr.append("<td></td>");
            tr.append("<td></td>");


            $('#GraphTable').append(tr);

        }
        else {

            tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append("<th colspan='10' style='text-align:center'>No Data to display</th>");

            $('#GraphTable').append(tr);
        }

    } //end of success
});
```

Comment: whats your data that is coming in?

Comment: If possible, I'd strongly suggest fixing this in the server side code that you call from the AJAX request.

Comment: @beginner ... I agree with Rory that the best solution, but there may be scenario where you can't edit on the serve side code, in that scenario we need sample ajax response to help you out. Again I'm saying if possible to change the server side code then I will go with Rory's statement.

Comment: Hello all, I cant edit the data on server side. Can we try in ajax itself? here the data is "Completion date & total amount for each completion date" Through completion date I am getting the month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my solution by:

```
 var tr;
                    var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
                    var monthsAmt = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        var date = new Date(data[i].CompDt);
                        var monthIdx = monthNames[date.getMonth()];

                        switch(monthIdx)
                        {
                            case "Jan": monthsAmt[0] += data[i].TotalAmt;
                                break;

                            case "Feb": monthsAmt[1] += data[i].TotalAmt;
                                break;

                            case "Mar": monthsAmt[2] += data[i].TotalAmt;
                                break;

                            case "Apr": monthsAmt[3] += data[i].TotalAmt;
                                break;

                            case "May": monthsAmt[4] += data[i].TotalAmt;
                                break;

                            case "Jun": monthsAmt[5] += data[i].TotalAmt;
                                break;

                            case "Jul": monthsAmt[6] += data[i].TotalAmt;
                                break;

                            case "Aug": monthsAmt[7] += data[i].TotalAmt;
                                break;

                            case "Sep": monthsAmt[8] += data[i].TotalAmt;
                                break;

                            case "Oct": monthsAmt[9] += data[i].TotalAmt;
                                break;

                            case "Nov": monthsAmt[10] += data[i].TotalAmt;
                                break;

                            case "Dec": monthsAmt[11] += data[i].TotalAmt;
                                break;
                        }

                    }
                    for(var i =0;i<12;i++){
                        if(monthsAmt[i])
                            {
                            tr = $('<tr/>');
                        tr.append("<td>" +monthNames[i] + "</td>");
                        tr.append("<td>" + monthsAmt[i] + "</td>");
                        $('#GraphTable').append(tr);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

update below code in success.

```
success: function (data) {
    if (data.length > 0) {

        var tr;
        var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun","Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

        var monthsAmt = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var date = new Date(data[i].CompDt);
            var monthIdx = monthsAmt[date.getMonth()];
            monthsAmt[monthIdx] += data[i].TotalAmt;
        }

        for(var i =0;i<12;i++){
        if(monthsAmt[i])
            tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append("<td>" +monthNames[i] + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + monthsAmt[i] + "</td>");
            $('#GraphTable').append(tr);
          }
        }
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            total = total + data[i].TotalAmt;
        }
        $('#GraphTable').append('<tr style="font-weight: bold; background-color: white"><td colspan="2" align="right">Total: </td><td>' + total + '</td></tr>');
        tr = $('<tr style="font-weight: bold; background-color: white" />');
        tr.append("<td></td>");
        tr.append("<td></td>");


        $('#GraphTable').append(tr);

    }
    else {

        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<th colspan='10' style='text-align:center'>No Data to display</th>");

        $('#GraphTable').append(tr);
      }
    } //end of success
});
```

Comment: Hi, I tried out your code. Its adding up all the amount and displaying as Jan. Not working

Comment: @beginner can you please share your fiddle?

Comment: Hi I have made some changes to the code and its working now. Check the Answer I will be posting. I am going to upvote for your answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

this may work:

```
var result=[];

        success: function (data) {
                if (data.length > 0) {

                    var tr;
                    var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun","Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        var totalAmt=0;
                         if(data[i].CompDt==data[i+1].CompDt)
                         {  
                            totalAmt= data[i].totalamt+data[i+1].totalamt;
                            result.push({'Month':data[i].CompDt, 'TotalAmount':totalAmt})
                         }

            } //end of success
        });
```

Comment: @beginner I have added the `if` condition. kindly change the lower part according to result  array

Comment: `if(data[i].CompDt==data[i+1].CompDt)` not every time months will be in next to each order. so that will not work

Comment: @yogendarji, as per question there is no recommendation that jan can come after march. it will be in order always. we consider all months in an order. it can't be *jan, mar ,jan*

Comment: Then what about last two records Dec, Dec?
It will throw an error